# Firebase transaction latency

Tags: firebase

Scenario: running a transaction.

I thought that information about whether the transaction was committed should be received roughly at the same time as 'value' event on other clients. That doesn't seem to be the case (100+ ms delay). Is this expected behavior (if so, how could i measure the difference) or am I doing something wrong?

coffeescript code

```
# CLIENT 1
ref.transaction (-> 1), (e, c, d) ->
  console.log "I'm first!" if c

# CLIENT 2
ref.on 'value', (d) ->
  console.log "I'm much later"
```

[here's an example (run this in two windows next to each other)](http://jsfiddle.net/bu65e/5/)
red circle (transaction) catching up to blue circle (set)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless it is a highly contentious Firebase location (e.g. 100,000+ simultaneous users trying to transaction() the same location) there shouldn't be that type of latency involved. Also, note that Firebase is currently only deployed in the United States. We will be rolling out worldwide in the near future, but network latencies could also be playing a role here.

[Here's a simple example counter that uses transactions](http://bit.ly/17PwMVx) — give it a try from multiple browsers to see what the latency looks like from your connection. The latency is imperceptible from my connection.

Comment: [this shows the difference](http://jsfiddle.net/bu65e/5/). Red circle is doing 'transaction' and blue circle is doing 'set'. Run this in two different windows or browsers and you'll see red circle always catching up.

Comment: That looks about right—transactions are definitely more expensive given the guarantees and data consistency promises we make. We'll continue to optimize areas like this, but at this time, the behavior shown in your example code is expected.

Comment: I just got here -- over two years after these comments -- loaded up the jsFiddle, from the first comment, on a couple of browser windows. The circles move in unison. At least, I can't see any visual difference -- very low latency. Pretty slick.

Comment: I tried this a few months ago and it was working, but now it isn't.